# Can I use FCM firebase without their firebase DB?

Tags: laravel, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have `Laravel` project and I need to seed notifications from web to mobile (android,iOS)  via API, a lot of recommendations goes to Firebase FCM (Firebase Cloud Messaging), but I have a question: can I use FCM of Firebase without using the DB of Firebase just unsing my own DB which is  `MYSQL` ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use Firebase Cloud Messaging without using any of the other Firebase products.

Just call the FCM REST API from your code, or use the Firebase Admin SDK, after reading the relevant data from your MySQL database.

Comment: could you pls recommend some blog post or video that you try it personally ?

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message?